# Scrolling image and text area within a container in Lwuit J2ME

Tags: java-me, scroll, textarea, containers, lwuit

I want to put an image with a text area (Y-axis) in a box layout container ,if the user presses the down button to scroll down, i want the container to scroll as a one object, so the image goes up while scrolling and the user scroll the rest of the text area content.
I know how to add the image and the text area to the container but i don't know how to do the rest.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you have to do following steps.

1. Set scrollable property of form to false.
2. Set scrollableY property of container to true.
3. Set the layout of form to BorderLayout.
4. Add the container to form at BorderLayout.CENTER.

Comment: I want to put an ad below the container , how to do that, if i changed the height of the container or the text area the container won't scroll